# Is Lazy.js a drop-in replacement for Underscore like Lo-Dash?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

My team is making the switch from Underscore to Lo-Dash or Lazy.js.  It looks like Lazy.js actually performs better than Lo-Dash most of the time, which is how these two libraries mainly compete.  I know that Lo-Dash is a drop-in replacement for Underscore and Underscore Stringify, but I couldn't find if Lazy.js is too.  I am asking this because we want there to be seamless integration when replacing the Underscore library.

Comment: Apart from not knowing whether it's a drop in replacement, here's something from the library's website: **This library is experimental and still a work in progress**. So, I couldn't find whether it has the same interface as Underscore or Lo-Dash, but the fact it's developed by a single person and still in experimental phase would be a deciding factor for me. Also, I have been using Underscore and Lo-Dash for years now and I never had a performance issue that forced me to entirely swap out a utility library.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a drop in replacement, although according to its own web site, it is purportedly faster.

One of the potential draw backs is that it doesn't have near the user base as lodash/underscore.